# How to make a GitHub Actions script publish a package only after direct changes on main or *after* a P.R. gets merged?

Tags: package, github-actions, workflow, publish, continuous-deployment

I am trying to build a Continuous Deployment workflow via GitHub
Actions.

As a background context, this is a Clojure/ClojureScript project -
specifically, a dependency on a dynamic web app.

As the outcome of the CD workflow, I want to have Maven packages
published on GitHub packages after every time the file `project.clj`
is changed.

Why this file? Because it holds the project version! Usually, when
someone edit this file it is because it is a new version. Hence, it
makes sense for a new version to be automatically published as a
dependency.

Ok. I have achieved something **close** to what I want. Packages have
been automatically published!

However, they are being published even when someone JUST submits a Pull Request.

I want the package to be published (CD to be triggered) on the
following conditions:

1 - after direct changes on `main` branch; or,

2 - after a Pull Request is *MERGED*.

I **do not** want a package to be published if the Pull Request is
**only submitted.**

This is my `cd.yml` file:

```yaml
name: 'cd'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'project.clj'
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'project.clj'
```

What do I need to change on the workflow dispatch?

Only removing the last 3 lines will do the trick?

Comment: Both conditions 1 and 2 are covered by the `push` trigger that you already have defined so... yeah, remove `pull_request` trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by my own questions and endorsed by user @[tmt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772810/tmt), removing the last 3 lines worked out as expected:

```yaml
name: 'cd'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'project.clj'
```